# AT-Mega 2560 analog pins

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, temperature

I am trying to measure the temperature from four MCP9700AE temperature sensors (http://www.digikey.ca/product-detail/en/microchip-technology/MCP9700A-E-TO/MCP9700A-E-TO-ND/1212508) using an ATMega 2560 microcontroller. However I get different temperature readings depending on which 5V input on the board and which ground on the board I use. I measured the potential difference between the 5V inputs and grounds using a multi-meter and they are all the same. So I don't understand why the temperatures are different. Anyone have any ideas?

By the way I tested this using two different AT Mega 2560s and the results were the same.

So I hooked up a 10 DOF sensor that has a temperature sensor as well to the ATMega. (https://www.adafruit.com/product/1604)

This chip requires an SDA and SCL connection. Now all the temperature sensors give 21 C temperature reading. Not sure what this modification does as I didn't change anything for the MCP9700A.

Comment: Have you tried reading the voltage on the same input **multiple times**. I once found that reading the voltage directly after switching inputs is unreliable but if I read it a second time, the voltage is OK.

Comment: What about each pin's average?

Comment: The pin averages all match for each ground and voltage input, I have tried it multiple times, yet the problem persists.

Comment: How different are the voltages / temperatures you measure ? What are the voltages ? Does the voltage read by the ADC match what you measure with a multimeter ? You have to provide more details.

Comment: The temperatures I got were 24 C, 30 C and 50C, so they are widely different.  The multimeter measures 5V between any ATMega 5V output and ground on the AT Mega.

Comment: I measured the room temperature using a different temperature sensor and it was measured to be 22.3 C.

Comment: Which 5V pins (of the Arduino board?) did you use?

Comment: I tried using both. There are only 2.

Comment: @user3897744 - (a) Try putting a decoupling capacitor (0.1uF to 1.0uF MLCC or similar) close to the MCP9700AE and re-test. Has that made the temperature readings more consistent between tests? (b) Do you have an oscilloscope? If so, use that instead of the multimeter, to measure the 5 V supply to the MCP9700AE. (High speed noise will not show on your multimeter readings and so *perhaps* this is giving you a false impression that your 5 V supply is stable.) Edit: Note that section 4.3 in the datasheet has specific guidelines for PCB layout and decoupling. Are you following those?

Comment: @SamGibson I missed that section. I will get a decoupling capacitor, that may very well be the solution. The signal is definitely noisy since the temperatures measured do change a lot as I sample them. However they are never near the room temperature. Also it does not explain why the  temperatures measured are in the 50 C region when using a particular 5 V output from ATMega and GND versus a different combination of 5V output and GND from ATMega where temperatures are in the 30 C region. Capacitors would reduce the oscillations but I am not sure about this DC offset.

Comment: @user3897744 - Without oscilloscope screen captures, I'm not trying to explain *all* of the behaviour you describe. The idea of my suggestion is just to see if adding decoupling makes any improvement at all, to any test. If it does improve the consistency of your measurements, then that confirms you have power-related problems. That result doesn't attempt to explain what those problem(s) are - however it does give you a pointer about where to focus your troubleshooting.

Comment: @user3897744 - From your latest update: "Not sure what this modification does [...]" One thing which adding that module does, is to add some extra capacitance across the power input to the module... If you carefully remove that module, touching nothing else, and your "varying temperature readings" problems start again, then it is something electrical about adding that module, which causes the improvement in behaviour of your temperature readings - yes?

Comment: Yea when I remove Vin to 10DOF chip, problem starts up again. If adding it does add in some capacitance I guess that could be the issue. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @user3897744  "Yea when I remove Vin to 10DOF chip, problem starts up again" That fits with the hypothesis that one "benefit" from that Adafruit module is the extra capacitance which it adds to its 5 V supply rail, which also powers the MCP9700A devices. Therefore I've written this up as an answer, along with the test you can do for confirmation, of adding just decoupling capacitor(s) instead of the Adafruit module.  Unfortunately I don't see a schematic on the Adafruit page to give you a clue about what capacitance to add - I would start at around 1uF, but other values may also work.

Answer (score 3):

> So I hooked up a 10 DOF sensor [...] Now all the temperature sensors give 21 C temperature reading. Not sure what this modification does as I didn't change anything for the MCP9700A.
>   [...]
>   when I remove Vin to 10DOF chip, problem starts up again [...]

From these updates in the question and subsequent comments, this behaviour fits with insufficient decoupling on the 5 V power supply to the MCP9700A devices.

The reason that adding the [Adafruit 10 DOF module](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1604) makes the MCP9700AE readings correct, could be because that Adafruit module includes at least one capacitor on the 5 V rail, as the input capacitor to its onboard LDO regulator (see red arrow below). So one side-effect of connecting this Adafruit module to the 5 V supply from the Arduino (which also powers the MCP9700A devices) is that it adds this extra capacitance to that power supply rail.

[image: Adafruit 10DOF module with power input capacitor marked]
<sub>[original image source](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/1200x900/1604-01.jpg)</sub>

Therefore, based on the results seen, I suspect that noise on the 5 V power supply to the MCP9700A devices could be the cause of the erratic readings. And connecting the Adafruit module adds enough capacitance to that 5 V supply to reduce noise and prevent the erratic readings from those MCP96700A devices.

Further confirmation would be possible, by adding only decoupling capacitor(s) to the 5 V power rail instead of connecting that Adafruit module, and seeing the same stable readings from the MCP9700A.

Comment: Good points. I didn't even look at the module when writing my answer.

Comment: @transistor - Thanks. I think we both realised that the power supply voltage *at the device* was likely to be involved - but from different "angles" :-) I've seen similar situations with debuggers e.g. system works only with debugger attached, and it later turns out that its the capacitor *inside the debugger* across the *target device's* power supply which is making the original system work. Remove the debugger (including its capacitor across the target supply) and there was insufficient decoupling for the target system to work! With an oscilloscope, it would be easier to debug these issues.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

*From the [datasheet](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/DevTools/LilyPad/MCP9700.pdf) we can calculate the expected output voltage.*

The DC electrical characteristics show that for the MCP9700A

- \$ T_C = 10~mV/°C \$.
- \$ V_{0°C} = 500~mV \$.

From this we can calculate that at your room temperature of 22.3°C the voltage you measure between \$ V_{OUT} \$ and \$ V_{SS} \$ should be as follows:

$$ V_{OUT} = 10m \cdot 22.3 + 500m = 223m + 500m = 723~mV $$.

- Check your voltages at the pins of the chips. All should give the same output. Note that the MCP9701 has a different output coefficient and 0°C voltage.
- While you're at it, check the supply voltage reaching the chips. It must be between 2.3 and 5.5 V.

These tests will show you if you have an analog problem with the sensors or a digital problem with your micro.

Report back.

Comment: I get 28 C and measure 800 mV. All the outputs differ slightly, one is 804 mV, 830 mV, 803 mV.

Comment: You get 28°C where? You get 800 mV where? On one sensor? On all sensors? You need to be specific about what you are measuring and put at least as much effort into your questions as I've put into the answer. If your sensors are in a 28°C environment you should get \$ 10m \cdot 28 + 500 = 780 mV \$ so you're 2°C out in your readings (2 x 10 mV). Datasheet says "±2°C (max.), 0°C to +70°C (MCP9700A/9701A)" so that plus the uncertainty of your 28°C reference reading seems OK. Now you need to look at how you've connected them to your micro. OK. I see you've updated your comment to give more detail.

Comment: If you have some heatsink compound stick them all onto the same piece of metal to even out the temperatures and measure again.

Comment: 28 C for Analog pin 0, and 800 mV when I measure the potential difference between that pin to ground. 29 C for Analog pin 1, and 804 mV when I measure the potential difference between Analog Pin 1 and ground. 31 C for Analog pin 2, 830 mV when I measure potential difference between Analog Pin 2 and ground. 28 C for Analog Pin 3, 803 mV when I measure the potential difference between Analog Pin 3 and ground.  I see that there is a +/- 2C margin. Thats fine, but the room is not 28 C, it feels cold, also a different temperature sensor I use tells me that it is 21 C.

Comment: I do not have heat sink compound, right now everything connected on a breadboard.

Comment: What ground are you using for those readings. In the answer I recommended that you measure between the pins _at the MPC9700s_ so that you don't include any voltage drops caused by bad breadboard contacts. (1) Is that the way you measured? (2) Measure the voltage between the ATMega's GND and the chip ground. 60 mV would knock your readings out by 6°C.

Comment: I was using the ground on the ATMega. When I directly between the ground on the MPC9700 and the Vout of the chip I get an unstable reading around 790 mV. There is a 10 mV difference between the ATMega ground and the chip ground.

Comment: Looking at your update it seems that you have inadvertently fixed a bad ground connection. You should be OK now. What I was trying to show you was to check the signals _at source_ to deduce where the problem lay.

Comment: I am not sure if it is a bad ground connection because I tried this on two different AT Megas, but thank you for your help.